# Apache Remove Local IP 192.168.x.x on live site

Tags: linux, web-services, apache, http

I normally use my local ip `http://192.168.x.x/domain.com` to test locally. How can I configure Apache to change that to `http://domain.com` removing my local ip.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention its your local ip, i'm going to assume that you working on your own machine or some personal server. I will also assume you have your domain.com dns pointing at the right ip address (if that is not the case you can test this by adding a line to your /etc/hosts with that map).

I'm going to assume also you want 
all calls to your webserver to go into /path/to/website/domain.com. (as another poster has covered another possible interpretation)

To do that you need to set in the appropriate config file (this will vary depending on your linux distribution) the following :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
     ServerName domain.com
     DocumentRoot /path/to/website/domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: +1, note that on Windows, the hosts files is in %{WIN_DIR}\System32\drivers\etc\hosts OTOH (no Windows to check here ;) )

Comment: @Wrikken thanks for the fix, still struggling with the syntax a bit :)

Comment: The `{}` button helps, and otherwise, just put 4 spaces in front of code :)

Answer (score 0):

In the relevant apache configuration file (e.g. apache2.conf or 000-default) you should see an entry something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ServerName www.domain.com
        ServerAlias domain.com
```

You will need to edit the ServerName and ServerAlias nodes to match `domain.com` for your case.